# Background fade in css - fallback for older browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have the following class for nav hover which simply adds a background image on hover..

```
 nav a:hover, nav a:focus, nav a:active {
     background:url(../images/goldNavBG.png) repeat-x;
  }
```

I would like to add a simple css3 fade in effect - but am worried about a fallback for old browsers as it needs to support ie7 +, is it possible to cater for both - so its simply shows a bg for older versions and doesn't break anything!?

Cheers

Comment: Did you ever try my solution? It should solve your problem.

Comment: cheers Joe - yep that will do the trick..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
nav a{
    /* your other styles */
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: background 0.5s linear;
    transition: background 0.5s linear;
}

nav a:hover, nav a:focus, nav a:active {
   background:url(../images/goldNavBG.png) repeat-x;
}
```

On non-CSS3 compatible browsers the background will just be replaced with no transition.

Here's a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/Vq34s/1/